# How would you stop a thread when the Window is closing and

Tags: c#, multithreading, window

...the class with the running thread is far away from the closing_event of the window.

btw. we use composite application block from MS.

Comment: how far? across town? different area codes?

Comment: If the running thread is a background thread it will be stopped for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Named Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433b98s3(VS.80).aspx) to communicate with you far-away-thread.